# RoR: Comparing param value to object's value not working for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, parameters

I'm trying to create a simple method of authentication for a site where the user that inserts an entry can put in a simple passcode to delete the entry if they want.  The site is just for RSVP's for a potluck so nothing secret, and I'm new to RoR so I thought it would be an easy exercise.  However I'm having a comparison issue with the params result and the known passcode.

Inline debugging in the Dishes controller

```
    puts "Original"
    puts @dish.passcode.to_s
    puts "Test"
    puts params[:pass]
    puts "Comparison"
    puts params[:pass] == @dish.passcode
    if @dish.passcode == params[:pass]
```

The output to the std out

```
    Original
    1234
    Test
    {"pass"=>"1234"}
    Comparison
    false
```

I've also tried .to_s and I get the same results.  Any assistance would be nice, I've exhausted Google and my patience with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output above, the line

```
puts params[:pass]
```

is printing

```
{"pass"=>"1234"}
```

This is a `Hash` not a `String`

I'm not sure what's going on with your parameters, but it looks like the value is in `params[:pass][:pass] that you want to compare.

If you check out your log (by default in development at `log/development.log` you should see all parameters.  This can be useful for debugging.

Comment: Thanks, that did work.  I'm not sure what's wrong with these parameters either since to me it looks wrong.  Like I said this program is a learning opportunity so I'll mess around with it more.

Comment: I was using the text_field instead of the text_field_tag in the view which is what caused the issue.